# Different directory to load function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery load function to replace iframe basically, since it loads only the section better.

It's working fine but the image is having problem since the directory of the image is placed inside `about.php` page, and i'm trying reaching it from `folder/editor.php`.

> About.php directory - images/img.jpg
>
> Editor.php directory - ../images/img.jpg

**Editor.php** - Notice I have tried to use different directory on this page.

```
<style>
  .content-page .hero {
      height: 250px;
      background-image: url("../images/header-background.jpg");/*url("/images/headers/header-background.jpg");*/
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
  <div id="iframe"></div>
  <script>
    $('#iframe').load('../about.php #content');
  </script>
```

**About.php**

```
<div id="content">
<style>
    .content-page .hero {
        height: 250px;
        background-image: url("images/header-background.jpg");/*url("/images/headers/header-background.jpg");*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>

<!-- Content goes here -->

</div>
```

How can I change css image source attribute after load function goes into action?

Comment: Since you aren't using a real iframe, I would add the CSS into the main page and just add the HTML content from the sub pages into the #iframe div. If the elements are correct, I believe the CSS should be auto applied to the new elements.

Comment: @imvain2 is there any way to add CSS through Javascript instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually did two questions: how to change the style, and how to do it after `$.load` executed. About the first one, there are several ways. About the second, you could use the `callback` argument, the third `$.load` argument.

From the code you posted it seems you actually don't want to change the background image, it seems you want to keep the same, simply you have some problems due to the directories.

The cleanest solution would be to write a `.css` file and include it in both the pages rather than to spread `<style>` elements in your pages with identical content.

Another solution could be to use absolute paths rather than relative paths: `/images/header-background.jpg` (if your image directory is in the root of your web server) rather than `images/header-background.jpg` or `../images/header-background.jpg`.

If you strictly need to keep this architecture changing your `About.php` as follows could be another possible solution.

```
<style>
    .content-page .hero {
        height: 250px;
        background-image: url("images/header-background.jpg");/*url("/images/headers/header-background.jpg");*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>
<div id="content">

<!-- Content goes here -->

</div>
```

Comment: That works, It didn't accord to me that javascript using load before rendering the page. anyway thank you.